# How to make multiple links go into mulple lines if they cant fit divs width

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains X amount of Links. These link auto space themselves in the div so they stretch from left to right.

But what if there is to many link then they just "runs" out of the div. Is there a way to make them go into multiple lines to solve this automatically ?

**Note** press the button to see the problem (*the button is only here to show you the problem*).

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('div').width(200)
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=A">A</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=B">B</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=C">C</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=D">D</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=E">E</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=F">F</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=G">G</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=H">H</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=I">I</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=J">J</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=K">K</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=L">L</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=M">M</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=N">N</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=O">O</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=P">P</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Q">Q</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=R">R</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=S">S</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=T">T</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=U">U</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=V">V</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=W">W</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=X">X</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Y">Y</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Z">Z</a>
</div>

<button>set width</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add `flex-wrap: wrap;` to your CSS, and it will wrap the child elements within the parent.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('div').width(200)
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=A">A</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=B">B</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=C">C</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=D">D</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=E">E</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=F">F</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=G">G</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=H">H</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=I">I</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=J">J</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=K">K</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=L">L</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=M">M</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=N">N</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=O">O</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=P">P</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Q">Q</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=R">R</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=S">S</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=T">T</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=U">U</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=V">V</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=W">W</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=X">X</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Y">Y</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Z">Z</a>
</div>

<button>set width</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `flex-wrap: wrap`, like:

```
div {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.fixed {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

And in **JS** add a class to `div` (in my case its `fixed`) to align the links:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('div').width(200);
  $('div').addClass('fixed');
})
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('div').width(200);
  $('div').addClass('fixed');
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div.fixed {
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

div a{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=A">A</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=B">B</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=C">C</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=D">D</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=E">E</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=F">F</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=G">G</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=H">H</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=I">I</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=J">J</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=K">K</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=L">L</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=M">M</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=N">N</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=O">O</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=P">P</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Q">Q</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=R">R</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=S">S</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=T">T</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=U">U</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=V">V</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=W">W</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=X">X</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Y">Y</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Z">Z</a>
</div>

<button>set width</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way so the Links in the last line floats left?

Comment: @PeterHansen Updated the answer, have a look.

Comment: That is what i want, but the button is only for the display of the problem, i dont have the buttom in the html page

Comment: @PeterHansen Then you need to apply `justify-content: flex-start;` to your `div`

Comment: I guess the answer is No, That it cant scale Automatic the way i want it to.

Comment: @PeterHansen You are right. You need to get the event as soon as the width is getting shorter so that you can do something like I've done.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have pointed out: `flex-wrap: wrap` wraps the elements to multiple lines.

The problem here is that `justify-content: space-between` doesn't know how to left-justify the last line.

As a workaround you could add some hidden elements at the end of the list of items (one less that the number of elements in one line)

This way flexbox will allocate space for them, but on the other hand they won't be visible because of the CSS which hides them.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('div').width(200)
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

div a{
  display: inline-block;
  flex: 0 0 7%;
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=A">A</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=B">B</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=C">C</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=D">D</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=E">E</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=F">F</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=G">G</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=H">H</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=I">I</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=J">J</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=K">K</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=L">L</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=M">M</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=N">N</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=O">O</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=P">P</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Q">Q</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=R">R</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=S">S</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=T">T</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=U">U</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=V">V</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=W">W</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=X">X</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Y">Y</a>
  <a href="Index.aspx?index=Z">Z</a>
  <a href="#" class="hidden"></a>
  <a href="#" class="hidden"></a>
  <a href="#" class="hidden"></a>
  <a href="#" class="hidden"></a>
  <a href="#" class="hidden"></a>
  <a href="#" class="hidden"></a>
  <a href="#" class="hidden"></a>
  <a href="#" class="hidden"></a>
</div>

<button>set width</button>
```